# How to manually repc Qt .rep to .h and then moc them to .cpp

Tags: qt, moc, qtremoteobjects

I'm trying to manually calling `repc` on my `.rep` files then running `moc` on the header output files.
`repc` runs successfully, but `moc` randomly complains about a

> parse error at '('

after a `Q_CLASSINFO` declaration. Any seen that issue before?

**Example**:

**remoteminimal.rep**

```
class RemoteMinimal
{
    SIGNAL(sendData(const QString &, const QString &));
    SLOT(void printData(const QString &));
    SLOT(void process(const QString &, const QString &));
    SLOT(void triggerSendData());
};
```

do

```
repc -i rep remoteminimal.rep -o replica rep_min_test.h
```

then

```
moc -o moc_rep_min_test.cpp rep_min_test.h
```

you'll get the following error:

> rep_min_test.h:20: Parse error at "("

Comment: you could explain in detail the steps that you use in addition to providing an example of problematic .rep

Comment: added example above

Comment: I recommend publishing the code in your question and not depend on an external resource, for example I could at some point delete my repo and your question could become unusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not linking Qt so MOC does not find some definitions. For these cases I prefer to analyze the code generated by qmake, and in the following fragment:

```
/usr/bin/moc ... rep_remoteminimal_replica.h -o moc_rep_remoteminimal_replica.cpp -I /usr/include/qt -I /usr/include/qt/QtRemoteObjects
```

You see that it is linked `/usr/include/qt`:

```
moc -I/usr/include/qt rep_min_test.h -o moc_rep_min_test.cpp
```

Comment: that's great, thanks. is there a "debug" or verbose mode for moc that complains about the lib not being accessible?

Comment: No, just analyze by erasing code :-) and analyze what was necessary, then just analyze why it was necessary